# Problems doing a POST request from android

Tags: android, django, http, httpurlconnection, django-csrf

I'm trying to login in a Django server from an android app, from the web it works fine, but when I try to do it from the app I get an Internal Server Error. I'm using HttpURLConnection:

```
url = new URL(loginUrl);
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
conn.getContent();
conn.disconnect();


CookieStore cookieJar =  cManager.getCookieStore();
List <HttpCookie> cookies = cookieJar.getCookies();
String csfr = null;
for (HttpCookie cookie: cookies) {
    Log.d("cookie", ""+cookie);
  if(cookie.getName()=="csrftoken"){
      csfr = cookie.getValue();
      break;
  }
}
String postParams = "csrfmiddlewaretoken="+csfr+"&username="+user+"&password="+pass+"&this_is_the_login_form=1&next=";

conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", ""+postParams.getBytes().length);
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0");
conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(postParams.getBytes().length);
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
dos.writeBytes(postParams);
dos.flush();
dos.close();
Log.d(conn.getResponseCode()+"", ""+conn.getResponseMessage());
```

The GET request works fine and fetch the csrf cookie just right, I don't know what I'm missing in the POST request. Here's a capture of the data posted from a browser request:

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken=zqvmoYTLeimB9RW5cMj5xTyLhIzR8kqr&username=user&password=123456&this_is_the_login_form=1&next=
```

edit:

Finally got it working, diasabled csfr protection, added some RequestProperty, read the response (getting pipe broken error en server side if not read) and added a '/' at the end of the URL. Porbably the causer of all or almost all of the error was the missing '/' on the url.

Final working coding:

```
url = new URL("http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX/accounts/login/");
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
conn.getContent();
conn.disconnect();

/*CookieStore cookieJar =  cManager.getCookieStore();
List <HttpCookie> cookies = cookieJar.getCookies();
String csfr = null;
for (HttpCookie cookie: cookies) {
  if(cookie.getName()=="csrftoken"){
      csfr = cookie.getValue();
      break;
  }
}*/
String postParams = "username=patient1&password=123456";

conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", ""+postParams.getBytes().length);
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,/;q=0.8");
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(postParams.getBytes().length);
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write(postParams.getBytes("UTF-8"));
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
while(is.read() > -1);

Log.d(conn.getResponseCode()+"", ""+conn.getResponseMessage());
```

Comment: Are you doing this operation in its own background thread (like asyncTask)?

Comment: Can you please post any logcat errors if any that your getting.

Comment: Yes, its on an asyncTask, an there are no error on the app side.

Comment: You should url-encode the params, e.g. `next=%2F` instead of `next=/`

Comment: already fixed this, it's not the problem

Comment: Why do you use "DataOutputStream". What's that? Why not just `os = conn.getOutputStream(); os.write(postParams.getBytes("UTF-8"))`?

Comment: That slash just costed me like 12 hours, and all i got was sore eyes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to disable [csrf protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) in your django login view.

Comment: I made a custom login view with the @csrf_exempt decorator, also works on the browser but I'm still getting the internal server error: 500

Comment: Can you put the DEBUG_MODE variable to TRUE and post the error you're getting?

Comment: How con I get this in the Android app?

Comment: In your Django project settings.py